# Ubuntu 18.04 Live Boot: Failed to create kernel channel

Tags: boot, nvidia, live-usb

I am trying to create a live boot of Ubuntu 18.04 to boot from my laptop but everytime I go to boot, I get a message saying

> failed to create kernel channel -22.

I've checked my BIOS settings and I have the Enable USB Boot setting enabled and Fastboot turned to thorough. I've also switched my graphics card's settings to only run off of the designated graphics card instead of integrated graphics.

Is there anything else I need to do or settings I need to switch in order to get the live boot to work or am I just SOL?

System Specs:

> Model: Dell XPS 15 7590
> Processor: Intel Core i9-9980HK
> GPU: GeForce GTX 1650
> OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Could the error be: `nouveau DRM: failed to create kernel channel -22`? In that case, add `nouveau.setmode=0` to your boot line in grub. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468275/should-i-use-nomodeset-nouveau-failed-to-create-kernel-channel-22) and [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101553). Any particular reason you're not using the latest and greatest (20.04 instead of 18.04)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is usually the open source nVidia driver (nouveau). You can add this to the kernel command line to disable modsetting of graphic:

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

On the Grub menu, you can press the 'e' on the selected menu and add the above code at the end of the kernel parameters and press F10 to boot with the edited menu.